# Can't format bibliography as i would like

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

i'm trying to include a particular reference in my bib. Below is what i've put in my bibtex file.

```
@UNPUBLISHED{goyalgagnon2015,
title={Social Structure, Markets and Inequality},
author={Gagnon, Julien and Goyal,Sanjeev},
note={Working Paper Series No: 2105/06},
institution={Cambridge-INET Institute},
year={2015}`
}
```

Here is the reference that shows up

"Gagnon, J. and S. Goyal(2015):  Social Structure, Markets and Inequality," Working Paper Series No:  2105/06."

As you can see, the institution isn't showing up. Any theories?

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: Package is natbib and style is ECTA (econometrica)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're using the wrong entry type: Instead of `@unpublished`, you should probably be using `@techreport` for the entry at hand.

Separately, instead of using the `note` field, you should be using separate `series`, `type`, and `number` fields. Finally, you may want to provide an `address` field as well.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
@techreport{goyalgagnon2015,
title={Social Structure, Markets and Inequality},
author={Gagnon, Julien and Goyal, Sanjeev},
series={Working Paper Series},
type = {Working Paper},
number = {2105/06},
institution={Cambridge-INET Institute},
address = {Cambridge UK},
year={2015}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{testbib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @SikandarSinghSoin - On this site, the preferred way to thank people for their answers is to (a) upvote the ones that (seem to) work -- you will be able to upvote answers once you've amassed 15 or more reputation points -- and (b) "accept" the answer that works best.

Comment: i was wondering what the big check mark did..